# Why am i getting a discrepancy in memory usage in my C application?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind, shared-memory

How can I understand the discrepancy between the 21 MiB of private memory bytes reported for my C application by ps_mem and the much smaller numbers reported by valgrind for current allocations.

[image: valgrind memory profiler]

System monitor shows below readings.

[image]

I've also used [ps_mem](https://github.com/pixelb/ps_mem/) to check used memory.

[image: ps_mem memory statistics]

Running proc/2101/smaps outputs the following. 4432 is the pid of my application.

[image]

Comment: valgrind shows you memory requested from the C standard library through `malloc()` and friends, system monitor tools show you the whole memory requested by the process from the operating system (which includes the code itself, static data, etc pp). As for your question: You probably shouldn't care but just go on and fix your leaks.

Comment: Valgrind isn't the tool of choice for memory _profiling_. Better have a look at "perf".

Comment: I don't see the inconsistency. Valgrind is telling you your program allocated 275M during its lifetime, not that it required 275M to run.

Comment: @Mat where does the screenshot say valgrind allocated 275M ? The heap summary shows 605, 760 bytes were used at program exit.

Comment: @electronicsalim, in the next line of heap summary: `275,999,630 bytes allocated`.

Comment: What exactly do you think is different in Valgrind and system monitor output?

Comment: "in use at exit" is what was still allocated when main returned, doesn't say anything about the max use of your program during its runtime.

Comment: @electronicsalim, perhaps you could narrow down your question by just asking "How can I understand the discrepancy between the 21 MiB of private memory bytes reported for my C application by ps_mem and the much smaller numbers reported by valgrind for current allocations."

Comment: If you can get this question unblocked, and if I am correct about what you are asking, I will answer your question for you if you post the results of ```cat /proc/<pid>/smaps``` where <pid> is the PID for your process.

Comment: Given that your PID was 4432 when you gathered smaps, you should have used "cat /proc/4432/smaps", not "cat /proc/2201/smaps".  Also, for someone to look at that smaps output they'll need to see the whole output, rather than just the last 20+ lines.   The point here is that the smaps output provides valuable clues as to how the memory is used.

Comment: @TimBoddy i was able to find the cause of the discrepancy, i had a part of my code doing repetitive unnecessary memory allocations. I caught the bug and my app consumes under 500Kb of memory. Thanks

Comment: @electronicsalim thank you for the update.  Given that this question is now unblocked and also unanswered, one choice you have is to answer it yourself and to provide details of what you did to figure things out.